# Injecting JavaScript via browser extension

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

Is it possible to inject JavaScript into a web-page with the help of a browser extension and guarantee that the page cannot override it? If this is not possible can the extension somehow check if its injected JavaScript is not used or something?

I want to deliver a JavaScript library over a safe channel, but I don't want it on a webserver.

Comment: Who are you trying to protect against? What would be overridden how by whom? What is the purpose of the library?

Comment: No, it's not practically possible for you to make an extension that's entirely resistant to detection, if it's doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for chrome extensions. There you'll have a way called "Content Scripts". I hope thats that what youre looking for!

Comment: Do they get a special namespace or something so they can't be overriden?

Comment: Content Scripts will be injected to the page youre on. What do you mean with namespace here?

Comment: I want to let webpages write "plugins" that use features of the browser extension. But I want to prevent webpages to override the core functionality.

Comment: Hm I cannot follow your mission exactly. But I recommend you to check out some chrome extension tutorials. Mybe the content scripts used there may be exactly what ur looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it :) I found `exportFunction()` to make extension function available for page scripts (like: `window.myFunction()`), but I don't know if they could simply be overridden (like: `window.myFunction = doEvil`)